# AWS Lambda Boto3 DynamoDB Concurrency

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, concurrent.futures

I am trying to use concurrent.futures to retrieve items from AWS DynamoDB asynchronously to shorten the function time.

```
def retrieve_dynamo_item(dynamo_tablename, key):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    dynamo_table = dynamodb.Table(dynamo_tablename)
    dynamo_result = dynamo_table.get_item(Key=key)
    return dynamo_result.get('Item')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    dynamo_queries = ## code
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(retrieve_dynamo_item, dynamo_table, key) for dynamo_table, key in dynamo_queries]

    final_result = []
    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        if f.result():
            final_result += f.result().get('result')
```

However when deploying and testing the lambda function performance does not seem to be improved but in fact worse than just running the queries synchronously. Any suggestions on what could be the reason?

Comment: You should use `batch_get_item` instead of `get_item`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Oleksii already said, the default memory setting of Lambda will only give you 1 CPU. So concurrency is kind of hard to achieve. The slower performance might be due to the added overhead of handling threads etc.

The following table contains the mapping of memory to CPU cores at this moment (could change in the future).

| Memory | CPU cores |
| --- | --- |
| 128 - 1769 | 1 |
| 1770 - 3538 | 2 |
| 3539 - 5307 | 3 |
| 5308 - 7076 | 4 |
| 7077 - 8845 | 5 |
| 8846 - 10240 | 6 |

So you could increase your Lambdas memory to 2000MB for example and check if that improves performance.

Furthermore, I'd definitely recommend using Batch operations instead of just `GetItem`.

Comment: the vcpu parameter actually states that you only get 0.x cpu per time, this accounts for the io wait, I would update the answer with vcpu parameter.

Comment: @OhadZadok Thanks for the update. I took those numbers from the official reInvent talks but googling did infact give me some unofficial stuff of this type of scaling. I'll investigate and will update with my findings. If you have any official sources I'd be thankful if you could link them.

Comment: you are right about the numbers, but I think you are missing the roles of cpus vs vcpu. The main problem in this question is not getting cpu time when the IO operation returns. vcpu control this. and with anything smaller than 1 vcpu the lag will occur. I actually experienced this myself and solved the problem when allocation 1 full vcpu.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel executions are most likely impacted by computing power available to the function. With default memory allocation you don't have much of CPU. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47256325/11305581) for more details